# Python search and replace in StringIO buffer?

Tags: python

I'm using [telnetlib](http://docs.python.org/library/telnetlib.html) to get a few lines of text (tn = telnetlib).

```
o = cStringIO.StringIO(tn.read_all())

# this prints the entire text as it should (a few lines)
print o.getvalue()
o.close()
```

Now, is there a way to search based on a string and replace an entire line in the cStringIO buffer if the string is found?
I did this with files on disk, but it's not very organised. The code is a mess and I need a lot of temporary files, I need to make a lot of search and replace operations.

Comment: Why are you putting the string `tn.read_all()` in a `StringIO` instance in the first place?  Search and replace will be easier on the bare string.

Comment: I see, will try it your way, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

small variant on @Sven Marnach's answer:

```
from cStringIO import StringIO
lines = tn.read_all().splitlines(True) # keep \n
o = StringIO()
for line in lines:
    if search_string in line:
        line = replacement_string # or line = line.replace(search_string, new_string) 
    o.write(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do the search and replace on the string, then put the result into the `StringIO` buffer if you need:

```
lines = tn.read_all().splitlines()
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    if search_string in line:
        lines[i] = replacement_string
o = cStringIO.StringIO("\n".join(lines))
```

Comment: This helps, but I still don't know how to search and replace within StringIO.

Comment: @zerg: The point of my answer is that it is pointless to search and replace within `StringIO`.  You can create a series of `StringIO` objects, read lines from one, replace if necessary, write result to the next one, if you want a more complicated and slower solution.